# How to wrap offending field in a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

It's displaying `<label>` tags with the error messages as default behaviour, however the way my CSS is set up I need a div to wrap around the offending element and a message display in `<p>` tags.

Without errors, my html looks like this:

```html
<div class="grid-26 append-2">
  <p class="noMarginBottom">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <div class="jNiceInputWrapper">
      <div class="jNiceInputInner">
        <input type="text" class="text jNiceInput" name="name" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </p>
  <span class="clear" />
</div>
```

And with errors, it needs to look like this. Note the `div` with class `error` and the `<p>` tag.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#contact_form").validate({
    rules: {
      name: {
        required: true
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid-26 append-2">
  <div class="error">
    <p>Please write your real name</p>
    <p class="noMarginBottom">
      <label>First Name</label>
      <div class="jNiceInputWrapper">
        <div class="jNiceInputInner">
          <input type="text" class="text jNiceInput" name="name" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </p>
    <span class="clear" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does anyone know how I can iterate through the errors so it performs this function on each error:
function showError(name, message) {
('[for='+name+']').parents('.append-2')
     .prepend('<p>'+message+'</p>')
     .wrapInner('<div class="error"></div>');
}

Answer (score 1):

Here's my full working code- I opted to use the default `<label>` tags rather than the `<p>` tags.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#contact_form").validate({
    rules:{
        name: {
            required: true
        },
    }
    ,messages: {
        name: "Please write your full name"
    }
    ,errorClass: "error_label"
    ,errorPlacement: function(error,element){
        parentDiv = element.parents('.grid-26');
        parentDiv.wrapInner('<div class="error"></div>');
        errorDiv = parentDiv.children(".error");
        error.appendTo(errorDiv);
    }
    ,success: function(element){
        var errorDiv = element.parents('.error');
        element.remove();
        errorDiv.siblings().remove();
        errorDiv.replaceWith(errorDiv.children());
    }

});
});
```

Thanks for your help Alex!!

Answer (score 0):

```
label.parents('.append-2')
     .prepend('<p>Please write your real name</p>')
     .wrapInner('<div class="error"></div>');
```

To restore it to its previous state:

```
var error = label.parents('.error');
error.siblings().remove();
error.replaceWith(error.children());
```

Comment: Thanks for that! It looks like it's going to be simpler than I though. However, I forgot to mention, there are many append-2 divs on the page. How can this code be modified so it walks up from the label? for instance `if label == name { parent.wrap('<div class="error></div>'); or something?

I just found out about the errorPlacement method for validation.. is this what I need to use?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with the particular jQuery plugin you're using, so I can't comment on the `errorPlacement` method it offers - hopefully you will find it useful though. I've updated the answer to show you how to walk up from _any_ element inside the `div`, including the `label`.

Comment: Great! I looked up some documentation to modify just one thing..
Since there are lots of labels on the page, I made it look for the attribute, so I did

    $('[for=name]').parents.......

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Feel cheeky asking, but do you know what code I need to use to remove these?

Comment: Try that. I've not tested, so if it doesn't work let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
        ,errorPlacement: function(error,element){

        $('[for='+element.attr("name")+']').parents('.grid-26')

        .prepend('<p>'+error.text()+'</p>')

        .wrapInner('<div class="error"></div>');

    }
```